# How to unpack 2d array of elements into a 3d array of columns and rows, maybe called a series?

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array, element

I am using Bloomberg sample code to collect data from Bloomberg through VBA (2d array?) and I have some old vba code that I believe takes a normal 3d array (maybe someone can clarify that for me). The problem is that Bloomberg output an array of elements.

See Bloomberg code below. Then below that is what I want to essentially convert the Bloomberg output into something that the next bit of code will accept.

```
Private Sub session_ProcessEvent(ByVal obj As Object)

On Error GoTo errHandler

Dim eventObj As blpapicomLib2.Event
Set eventObj = obj

If Application.Ready Then
    If eventObj.EventType = PARTIAL_RESPONSE Or eventObj.EventType = RESPONSE Then
        Dim it As blpapicomLib2.MessageIterator
        Set it = eventObj.CreateMessageIterator()

        Do While it.Next()
            Dim msg As Message
            Set msg = it.Message
            Dim securityData As Element
            Dim securityName As Element
            Dim fieldData As Element
            Set securityData = msg.GetElement("securityData")
            Set securityName = securityData.GetElement("security")
            Set fieldData = securityData.GetElement("fieldData")
            Sheet1.Cells(currentRow, 4).Value = securityName.Value
            Dim b As Integer

            For b = 0 To fieldData.NumValues - 1
                Dim fields As blpapicomLib2.Element
                Set fields = fieldData.GetValue(b)
                Dim a As Integer
                Dim numFields As Integer
                numFields = fields.NumElements

                For a = 0 To numFields - 1
                    Dim field As Element
                    Set field = fields.GetElement(a)
                    Sheet1.Cells(currentRow, a + 5).Value = field.Name & " = " & field.Value
                Next
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
            Next b
        Loop

        ' skip a row for next security
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    End If
End If

Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

This is the next bit of code I want the Bloomberg output to feed into.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Count() As Variant
Dim AdjCount() As Variant
Dim Rev() As Variant
Dim Conf() As Variant
Dim ncount() As Integer

Sub CreateSetupsBUY(series As Variant)
Dim x As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim temp1 As Variant
Dim temp2 As Variant
Dim temp3 As Variant
Dim temp4 As Integer
Dim temp5 As Variant

ReDim Count(UBound(series))
ReDim AdjCount(UBound(series))
ReDim Rev(UBound(series))
ReDim Confn(UBound(series))
ReDim ncount(UBound(series))

For x = LBound(series) To UBound(series)
    ReDim temp1(UBound(series(x)))
    ReDim temp2(UBound(series(x)))
    ReDim temp3(UBound(series(x)))
    temp4 = 0
    ReDim temp5(UBound(series(x)))

    For Y = LBound(series(x)) + 5 To UBound(series(x))
        If IsNumeric(series(x)(Y, 1)) Then

            If series(x)(Y, 4) < series(x)(Y - 4, 4) Then
                temp1(Y) = 1 + temp1(Y - 1)
            Else
                temp1(Y) = 0
            End If


            If series(x)(Y, 4) > series(x)(Y - 4, 4) Then
                temp5(Y) = 1 + temp5(Y - 1)
            Else
                temp5(Y) = 0
            End If

            If temp1(Y) > 9 Then
                temp2(Y) = 0
            Else
                temp2(Y) = temp1(Y)
            End If


            If temp1(Y) = 9 Then
                temp4 = temp4 + 1
            End If

            If series(x)(Y - 1, 4) >= series(x)(Y - 5, 4) Then
                temp3(Y) = 1
            Else
                temp3(Y) = 0
            End If
        Else
            temp1(Y) = 0
            temp2(Y) = 0
            temp3(Y) = 0
            temp4 = 0
            temp5(Y) = 0
        End If
    Next Y
    Count(x) = temp1
    AdjCount(x) = temp2
    Conf(x) = temp3
    ncount(x) = temp4
    Rev(x) = temp5
Next x

Call CreateCount(series, Count, Conf, ncount, Rev)

End Sub
```

When I tried connecting the two I get a type error. I assume its because of the way the Bloomberg array is created and unpacked.
Possible solution I have yet to try is to unpack the Bloomberg array and some how build a basic column row array while the Bloomberg array is unpacking.

Comment: How are you connecting the two? It looks like `session_ProcessEvent` is writing the data to an excel sheet. How are you passing this data to `CreateSetupsBUY`?

Comment: what is your ultimate goal? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Session_ProcessEvent is writing the data to excel. the output is 5 Columns (date, Open, high, low, close) and the rows are dates and the values are prices. It can output this information for multiple securities.
The CreateSetUpsBuy is looking for a 3D array(I believe)
How do I take the output of Session_processEvent and arrange it so that it works as an input for CreateSetUpsBuy?

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way to myArray(b,a)= "field.Value" but that is only a 2d array and I need a 3d array. 
so I need a way to create myArray(securityname, b,a)